# SAP Gateway get create ID as response

Tags: odata, abap, netweaver, sap-gateway

I'm using OData services to send data to an SAP system. 
When I'm doing a

```
oModel.create({data})
```

Is there any way to let the server give me as response the ID or field I just created in the database?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a very common use case.

Model the id as a field of your entity.

Leave the id empty when making the call from the Frontend.

The server fills the id field in the response.
In the response, the server may also change or fill any other field of the entity.

in your backend method `MYENTITY_CREATE_ENTITY`, do something like

```
io_data_provider->read_entry_data( IMPORTING es_data = ls_myentity ).

"create object in database which fills the field lv_id_from_database

ls_myentity-id = lv_id_from_database.
er_entity = ls_myentity.
```

Frontend:

```
oModel.create("/Myentity", 
    oDataCreate, null, false, 
         function(oData, oResponse){
                  //Function for Success
         },
         function(oData, oResponse){
                  //Function for Error
});
```

Comment: it seems like you knows how to solve this issue but I couldnt really

Comment: can you please also add which parameters the create method sould have in order to retrieve the response?  Thank you

Comment: added frontend example